# Is 10 fold test meaningful to measure overfitting?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

As far as I understand, a model is certainly overfitting if 1. converges too soon 2. validation loss keeps increasing

Again, to my knowledge, there is no way around this unless you make the validation loss converge to a similar trend to your training loss, so you can do more data augmentation etc.

However, so many papers I have read claims a 10 fold is a sign of robustness and shows the model is not overfitting. When I recreate those experiments though, I can say that they do overfit whether they show robust accuracies or not. Also, many people seem to think that they will just add a 10 fold and that is good to go. In the reviews also, they only ask for 10 fold experimentation to address overfitting.

Is my take wrong? Is there hope for a validation loss that does not converge but go up? Or is there a measure besides validation loss?

Answer (score 1):

I assume, by 10 fold test you mean 10 fold cross-validation.

Usually, cross-validation is useful only on very small datasets, i.e. with less than 1000 samples.

Overfitting means that the complexity of your model is much higher than necessary. A typical sign of overfitting is a very high learning accuracy vs low validation accuracy.

Therefore, use of 10 fold cross-validation may not prevent from overfitting per se.
Consider two examples:

First, learning accuracy 99.8%, 10 fold cross-validation accuracy 70%.

Second, learning accuracy 77%, 10 fold cross-validation accuracy 70%.

In both cases, the same 10 fold cross-validation resulted in 70% accuracy. However, the first case is clearly overfitting, whereas, the second is not.

I hope, this clarifies the situation.

Comment: I meant using 10 splits for experimentation, a lot of papers run this experimentation to be able to say they get close results every time (say around 70) but since they never write about how their model converges (learning loss), we can not know if they are overfitting or not

Comment: Also, shouldn't we check care more about losses?

Comment: I'm not sure if we need to care about losses in this case. It would be helpful if you can provide a typical example of such paper.

Comment: Alright, thank you, I think what you are saying is validating my understanding of overfitting, except I am more focused on losses, say I have a model with a learning acc of 92 and validation acc of 87, while the learning loss has converged to below 1% but validation loss is around 8, and in fact it never really converged (decreased for a while then increased again to a closer range than start). I think this model is overfitting

Comment: Many papers only provide a 10fold of test accuracies, and nothing on learning and I think some do actually overfit